# How to perform multiple list slices at the same time?

Tags: python, slice

Say I have a list:

```
L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

and I have a list of indices:

```
indices = (2, 5, 7)
```

What I would like to be able to do is slice the list at all 3 indices at the same time. In other words, id like to perform the following lines of code in one line:

```
sub1 = L1[:2]
sub2 = L1[2:5]
sub3 = L1[5:7]
sub4 = L1[7:]
```

I could fairly easily write a function that does this, but I was wondering if it is possible to do this in one expression.

Comment: do you want each slice to be in a different variable? if so, is the amount of slices always going to be the same?

Comment: I am looking for a generalized case, so any amount of indices assuming it fits within the length of the list.

Comment: theres no good way to set each to a new variable if you want it to be a general case but it is possible to set a key value pair in a dict like `d = {'sub1':l1[:2],'sub2':L1[2:5]...}` then you can get each slice with `d['sub1']` and such. or just to a list of strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for a one liner? We could give you one, but I would just keep it simple:

```
L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
indices = (2, 5, 7)

start = 0
sections = []
for end in indices:
    sections.append(L1[start:end])
    start = end
sections.append(L1[start:])

for part in sections:
    print part
# [1, 2]
# [3, 4, 5]
# [6, 7]
# [8, 9]
```

Comment: Yeah I would do something like this but I was wondering if there was a pre built tool for this occasion.

Comment: I doubt it. You're working with two separate concepts here: array slicing and iteration. It wouldn't make much sense for Python to write a function that packages these things together. You're best to write a function yourself.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with `slice` objects:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> get = itemgetter(slice(0, 2), slice(2, 5), slice(5, 7), slice(7, None))

>>> values = range(1, 10)
>>> values
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> get(values)
([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9])
```

Comment: +1 I think it's important to mention that besides being very elegant, the `itermgetter` plus `slice` combination also works with other types of sequences, like tuples and strings (including Unicode strings).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done in one expression, but it's not very readable:

```
seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
ind = (2, 5, 7)
print([seq[p:q] for p,q in zip((0,)+ind, ind+(len(seq),))])
```

**output**

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

If you really want to assign the sublists to separate names you can do it like this:

```
s1, s2, s3, s4 = [seq[p:q] for p,q in zip((0,)+ind, ind+(len(seq),))]
```

but it's probably better to just keep them in a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the help of some built-in functionality you could do it in one line. The 'biggest' problem is transforming the list of end points to a list of `(start,end)` tuples or `slice` objects.

The code below extends the `endpoints` list with 0 on one end and `None` at the other end and uses `zip()` to combine pairs of them. Then use the `operator.itemgetter()` trick to extract the slices:

```
import operator
ends = [2,5,7]
values = range(20)

operator.itemgetter(*[slice(*z) for z in zip([0]+ends, ends+[None])])(values)
```

Output:

```
([0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
```

Answer (score 0):

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are amazing.

Starting with your list:

```
>>> L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Pad your indices with `None`:

```
>>> indices = (None, 2, 5, 7, None)
```

Now comprehend away:

```
>>> [L1[start:stop] for start, stop in zip(indices[:-1], indices[1:])]
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```